# Regex works in regex101, but not in python code

Tags: python, html, regex

I have this text:

```
a href="#" class="s-navigation--item js-gps-track js-products-menu" aria-controls="products-popover" data-controller="s-popover" data-action="s-popover#toggle" data-s-popover-placement="bottom" data-s-popover-toggle-class="is-selected" data-gps-track="top_nav.products.click({location:2, destination:1})" data-ga="[&quot;top navigation&quot;,&quot;products menu click&quot;,null,null,null]" aria-expanded="false"
```

With this regex:

```
attr_regex = '(?:\w+[-\.]*)+(?:=+[\'\"][\w\d\s:;,$@#!\[\]^&?%*\/+(){}.=-]*[\'\"])*'
```

I want to separate this text into the individual words or variables there are, like this:
[image]

But instead, in python code the output gets like this (in a list):

```
['a', 'aria-controls="products-popover"', 'aria-expanded="false"', 'class="s-navigation--item js-gps-track js-products-menu"', 'data-action="s-popover#toggle"', 'data-controller="s-popover"', 'data-ga', 'top', 'navigation', 'products', 'menu', 'click', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'data-gps-track="top_nav.products.click({location:2, destination:1})"', 'data-s-popover-placement="bottom"', 'data-s-popover-toggle-class="is-selected"', 'href="#"']
```

As you can see there are some words which are not supposed to come out like that, because they are inside the value of the variable.

Python code:

```
elements = re.findall(attr_regex, str(text))
print(elements)
```

Using raw string doesn't fix the problem!

How can I fix this problem, and better, how can I make this regex work successfully in every text possible?

Comment: Please show your python code.

Comment: FYI you don't need to escape `.` inside `[]`, and you don't need to escape quotes in a regexp (you need to escape the quotes in the python string that match the delimiting quotes, but you can avoid that by using triple quotes around the string).

Comment: You should generally avoid using regular expressions to parse HTML. Use a DOM parser like Beautiful Soup.

Comment: I have to deal with other type of documents and using regex is just my main objective.

Comment: When I try your code `elements` begins with `['a', 'href="#"', 'class="s-navigation--item js-gps-track js-products-menu"',` which looks correct.

Comment: The code for setting `attr_regex` is not valid, it's missing quotes around the string. I put the regex inside a raw string. Please show your *actual* code.

Comment: I forgot the quotes sorry!